# How to find the sum of a series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to find the sum of the series
 $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^n\cdot x^{2n}}{n!}$$
Is there any general method for solving such problems?

Comment: Hint: We are looking at $\sum \frac{(3x^2)^n}{n!}$. No general method, but familiarity with the "standard" series is very useful.  Then we can add them, differentiate, integrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working with series, you should probably know the most famous one:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x.$$

So by collecting everything that is exponentiated to the $n$-th power in the argument of the sum, we get
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty3^n\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}  \\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(3x^2)^n}{n!} \\ =e^{3x^2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the Taylor Series for $e$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty3^n\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(3x^2)^n}{n!}=e^{3x^2}.$$